# Unable to install rpy2 on MAC OS due to ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo

Tags: python, rpy2, backport

I am trying to install rpy2 on my mac. I have tried to use the command `pip install rpy2` but I get the following error:

```
?25h  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I tried using the command : `pip install backports.zoneinfo` but that returned the same error.

Comment: I don't know if you need it anymore, but for anyone who gets redirected here: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73512185/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-backports-zoneinfo-error-while-installing-dja) worked for me. I was trying to install streamlit and getting same error.