# ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, Error while installing django

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm new to python development and I was trying using django but I'm facing this error while installing django using
`pip3 install django~=4.0`.
I tried few solution but none of them worked.
I already tried

- Upgrading pip to latest version
- `pip install backports.zoneinfo` but that too failed.
- pip install --upgrade pip wheel

I'm using Python 3.8.9 and mac M1

```
Collecting django~=4.0
  Using cached Django-4.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
Collecting backports.zoneinfo
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.5.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      /private/var/folders/bw/1s6x6hxx7zs5wdt200bhyn900000gp/T/pip-build-env-9dkhvyjx/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Users/apandey/env/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 29):

You should have this file on your computer.
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers/Python.h

If so, first run

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers
```

Then `pip install backports.zoneinfo`

Comment: it's working, but why do we have to export manually the C_INCLUDE_PATH ? I'm using Python 3.8.2 on a mac M1

Comment: It is also good to add it to ```.zshrc``` file and run ```source .zshrc```.

Comment: still not woking for me

Comment: I got this backports error when I was installing django on my mac. This answer resolved the error for me. Thanks Brendon